# Crop Profile Image on upload

Tags: 7, media

I come across different type of image crop, but the only one seems to work on the profile image is [Image Javascript Crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop) like says [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23321/13516).

The problem so far is that i need to crop the image on upload.
I can't find any way. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagefield_crop doesn't work on profile picture or either i can't find a way to make it work

You could disable the standard user picture (Configuration » People » Account ->  Personalization) and instead add your own custom image field, then Imagefield_crop will work.

Comment: that was not the simplest way to do.
Now I have to understand how to show the custom image in comment and similar, but it works

Answer (score 1):

The [Imagefield Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) module allows a user to crop the image after upload.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> When the user uploads an image, the image is presented inside a cropping area. A cropping box is shown inside, and the user can resize and move it. Upon clicking 'preview' or 'submit', the image is cropped and the result is saved instead of the original image.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Seamless, intuitive cropping, almost like using a desktop photo editing app
> - All major browsers supported
> - Dynamic preview - you see how your crop will look like, in real time!
> - Original image is saved for recropping.
> - No matter what resolution the cropping area is, the original image is used for cropping (for highest quality)
> - The sizes of the cropping area, cropping box and resulting image can be controlled by the administrator

Comment: Imagefield_crop doesn't work on profile picture or either i can't find a way to make it work

Answer (score 1):

> that was not the simplest way to do. Now I have to understand how to
>   show the custom image in comment and similar, but it works

[user picture field](https://drupal.org/project/user_picture_field)

Comment: what language is this, please use only English language.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for cropping an image:
If you are the admin then you could apply an image style to the image field.

Go to configuration -> media -> image-styles

Either add your own image style or edit any of the default image style.
And effects that you want to select like crop/rotate/desaturate/scale etc and save that configuration.

Now go to configuration -> media -> file-types -> Manage file display of the image

Now select any one from original/Default/link/preview/small/large

In that check the image checkbox. there select the image-style that you did the settings and save the configuration.
Now where ever you want to crop the image for eg in content type you want to add the image there select that image style.

Comment: I've already set this way, but i want to allow user to crop and resize their avatar on upload

Comment: Then you will have to make use of:

Either imagecrop module from http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop

Or ESPA crop module from http://drupal.org/project/epsacrop

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to make use of:

Either **imagecrop module** from http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop

Or **ESPA crop module** from http://drupal.org/project/epsacrop

Comment: either imagecrop or espa work.
The user have to upload the image, save the profile, then crop his image